# what is the explaination of the output of the given program

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

char *ptr = "helloworld"; printf(ptr);

Why it is printing helloworld as i haven't used *ptr in printf which should give the value like we use for pointer to an integer.

According to me it should we printf(*ptr) in printf

Comment: `printf(ptr);` is same as `printf("helloworld");`

Comment: thanks for your answer but ptr contains the address of the character 'h'right? so how we are able to imlicitly convert to a string.

Comment: The function signature for printf is `int printf(char *format, ...);`. The function expects a pointer to a "c string", which is a pointer to buffer of characters that is NULL terminated. RTM.

Answer (score 1):

For any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is exactly equal to `*(p + i)`.

If the index `i` is zero, then we have `p[0]` being exactly equal to `*(p + 0)`. Adding zero to anything is a no-operation, so it's `*(p)`. And the parentheses are not needed here which gives us `*p`.

So in your case `*ptr` would be the same as `ptr[0]`, which is the first character in the string. And *only* the first character in the string, with the type `char`.

A "string" is a null-terminated *sequence* of characters, and to use it we have a *pointer* to the first character. Which is what plain `ptr` (without dereference) is. And that matches the `printf` format string argument, which needs to be a *pointer* to the first character in the null-terminated string.

Comment: thanks for your answer but ptr contains the address of the character 'h'right? so how we are able to imlicitly convert to a string

Comment: There's no string type in C, only the convention that you provide a pointer to the first character in a buffer that is NULL terminated. `*pter` yields h, but printf increments `ptr` and prints the next character if and only if, it's not NULL.

Comment: @Pranjalakg Like I said, a string is a null (zero) terminated sequence of characters, and we reference the string using the *pointer* to the first character. In short, the `printf` function will take the pointer, print the first character (`ptr[0]`), then print the second character (`ptr[1]`) and so on until it reaches the terminator (which is at `ptr[10]`).

Comment: sure got it now

Answer (score 0):

`printf` expects its first argument to be a pointer to `char`:

> **7.21.6.3 The `printf` function**
> **Synopsis**
> 1     `#include <stdio.h>`
>        `int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);`

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

so

```
printf( ptr );
```

is correct<sup>1</sup>.  However, the usual practice for printing a plain text string is to do something like

```
printf( "%s\n", ptr );
```

rather than passing it *as* the format string.  Alternately, you could use the `puts` function:

```
puts( ptr );
```

since no formatting is involved.

The value in `ptr` is the address of the first character of the string - `printf` will print the *sequence* of characters starting at that address until it sees the string terminator<sup>2</sup>.

---

1. You can pass a `char *` argument to a function that expects a `const char *`, but not the other way around; you'll get a diagnostic on the order of "argument n discards `const`" or something like that.  The `restrict` keyword in the function declaration is basically an optimization hint - you don't need to worry about that right now.

   If it sees a *conversion specifier* in the format string like `%d` or `%f`, it will take the value of the corresponding argument and format it as the equivalent sequence of characters.